# How to link Libbluetooth for GCC?

Tags: gcc, linker

I am trying to use hci.h, hci_lib.h etc... in my c files. The final command to link the object files into exec look like this:

```
gcc -g3 -o execfile ./dev1.o ./dev2.o ./main.o ./nets.o `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0 gio-unix-2.0`
```

However I am getting linking error like this:

```
undefined reference to `hci_open_dev'
undefined reference to `hci_le_set_scan_parameters'
undefined reference to `hci_le_set_scan_enable'
undefined reference to `hci_le_set_scan_enable'
undefined reference to `hci_close_dev'
```

I know that this is because I am not specifying -lbluetooth to gcc.

Is there a way to specify the libbluetooth-dev to pkg-config like I do for glib & gio-unix above?

Comment: If your distro provides the package config file for libbluetooth, then you can use pkg-config with it.

Comment: @n.m. I think I search for the pc file for libbluetooth. Don’t remember finding it. I just installed it from command line. Perhaps I can look again.

Comment: If the pc file is not there, then how do you expect it to work?

Comment: @n.m. Well the link works fine if I specify it via -lbluetooth option. So I assume it must be there somewhere.

Comment: Could you help me understand what is the difference between -lbluetooth option vs specifying it via pkg-config

Comment: That's a good question that is deserved to be asked on its own.